# Implementing animation to run equally fast on all machines

Tags: java, animation, swt

What is the usual way to implement animations (e.g. a composite with a changing position, in SWT) so that they look equally fast on all machines?

The naive approach would be to use timestamps, to stop the time untill the next animation step.

Is there a more professional way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach is using timestamps; the naïve and professional approaches differ in *how* they are used.

The naïve approach uses a thread and `Thread.sleep()`. The professional approach uses timers to run code at certain intervals and let the timer decide how to handle delays and jitter.

You can learn more about timers, look at the classes `Timer` and `TimerTask`. `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, Date, long)` should be a good start. Just be aware that the code is executed in a new thread, so you need to use the usual tools to inject events into the UI thread's queue.

Comment: Is the example still available somewhere on internet?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) on a regular basis, and it works great for consistent animations. All you have to do is implement a class (you can even make it your `Frame` or `Panel`) that implements `ActionListener`.

The timer calls the `actionPreformed(...)` method at an interval specified in the constructor (or later if you want), and you can perform all of your redrawing from the `Timer` intervals. Usually that involves updating the state of whatever object you need and calling [`repaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) on the `Panel` involved.

Make sure you call the `Timer`'s `start()` method. That has caused me numerous headaches!